# What happens if use I undefined HTML tags instead of div In My Web

Tags: html, tags, undefined

What Will Happen If We Use

```
<container>
   <red>I'm Red If Working 100%</red>
</container>
```

**Instead Of Using**

```
<div class=container>
   <div class=red>
     I'm Red If Working 100%
   </div>
</div>
```

**Anyway CSS and JS is working**

```js
$("red").on("click", function(){ alert("Working 100%") });
```

```css
container{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  overflow:auto;
}
red{ color:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<container>
   <red>I'm Red If Working 100%</red>
</container>
```

**Is there Any Problems If We Use These ??**

Comment: Yes, at least i got an answer after a week, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Actually the `<container>` is a div block that has some additional properties.

> Container: Same as Div but locked at 960 pixel width and auto-placed
> in center of page

So of course it will work fine with JS and CSS

Comment: Oh, Anyway Can we use `undefined` tags, not like `container`. I mean is there any problems if use these